Angular: Scroll to a section on page load when navigating to a specific URL fragment
I'm working on an Angular application and I have a function that scrolls smoothly to a specific section on the page. The function works perfectly when I trigger it manually. However, I want the page to automatically scroll to a specific section when the user navigates directly to a URL with a fragment, such as http://localhost:4200/section-2.
How can I modify my code or implement additional logic to make sure that when the page is loaded with a specific fragment in the URL, it automatically scrolls to that section?
Here's my current scroll function:
public scrollToSection(sectionId: string): void {
  const targetElement = document.getElementById(sectionId);
  if (targetElement) {
    const navHeight = this.navigationService.getNavHeight();
    const yPosition = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - navHeight;
    window.scrollTo({ top: yPosition, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}



You should have a component to wrap all the sections. In this component, extract the first route path and scroll to the section.


home.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Section1Component } from '../section1/section1.component';
import { Section2Component } from '../section2/section2.component';
import { Section3Component } from '../section3/section3.component';
import { Section4Component } from '../section4/section4.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationService } from '../navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    Section1Component,
    Section2Component,
    Section3Component,
    Section4Component,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  template: `
    <app-section1></app-section1>
    <app-section2></app-section2>
    <app-section3></app-section3>
    <app-section4></app-section4>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private navigationService: NavigationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot &&
      this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot.length > 0 &&
      this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1].url.subscribe((url) => {
        let elementId = url[0].path;

        this.scrollToSection(elementId);
      });
  }

  public scrollToSection(sectionId: string): void {
    const targetElement = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    if (targetElement) {
      const navHeight = this.navigationService.getNavHeight();
      const yPosition =
        targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - navHeight;
      window.scrollTo({ top: yPosition, behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }
}


In your routes, point all the section URLs to the HomeComponent.


app.route.ts

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'section-1', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'section-2', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'section-3', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'section-4', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];


Provide the routes in the provideRouter function.


main.ts

import { routes } from './app/app.routes';

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations(), provideRouter(routes)],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


Currently, you do not utilize the route and render the component. You have to apply the <router-outlet> in the template in the main.ts. Remove the imports of the section components from the App.


main.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NavComponent,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  template: `
  <div class="container">
     <app-nav></app-nav> 
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  `,
})

Demo @ StackBlitz

Note: People may be more helpful if you write your questions more clearly.
I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but you can use these methods; I haven't tested the codes but it should work.
Angular;
If you defined the "section-2" part as a parameter as ":elementid" when defining routes;
Option 1: (Is static value. When it changes, it can be difficult to keep track.)
let elementId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['elementid'];
this.scrollToSection(elementId)

Option 2: (It can be tracked.)
this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
 map(params => params.elementid),
 switchMap(elementId=> this.scrollToSection(elementId)
);

Pure JS in Angular;
(There are other methods, too.)
let id = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
this.scrollToSection(id);

(It is generally recommended to use the angular method instead of js in Angular.)

I tried to formulate my question in an understandable way.  Your answer is not what I meant.  If I insert this URL http://localhost:4200/section-2 into the browser then I should scroll to component 2.  Currently there is no scrolling when the URL is entered via the browser.

If you think I misunderstood, can you take a look at this code? When I add "/section-2" to the url and refresh the page, it scrolls to the div with "section-2" id. If you didn't mean that, then I misunderstood.

I can't get it to work locally. Can you try if you can do it with this code? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bqamtc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav%2Fnav.component.ts

Edited Code . You need to scroll in OnInit in nav.component. For example: (You can also get the url path in other ways. This is just an example.)
ngOnInit(): void {     this.scrollToSection(location.pathname.substring(1));   }
